# Sql select query with where from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string

I have a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE  a(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    x varchar(50) 
)
```

I found that following query works

```
select cast (id as varchar(3))+cast (x as varchar(3)) c from a 
where cast (id as varchar(3))+cast (x as varchar(3))='1a'
```

but this does not work

```
select cast (id as varchar(3))+cast (x as varchar(3)) c from a 
where c='1a'
```

Does any one knows why is that?
Please not that for some reason I don't want to use

```
where id=1 and x ='a'
```

Comment: One of the idea is to create a view vwTest with 

select cast (id as varchar(3))+cast (x as varchar(3)) c from a 

and do the query  select * from vwTest where c = '1a'

Comment: You say: "Please not that for some reason I don't want to use where id=1 and x ='a'".  Please, please... whatever your reason is, it is **NOT** good enough. By choosing not use the most logical and sensible option, you entirely eliminate the possibility of using indexes, and your query & database will run slower for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because expressions in the `WHERE` clause are evaluated to restrict rows before expressions and aliases are evaluated in the select-list.

Here's a workaround:

```
select aprime.*
from (select cast (id as varchar(3))+cast (x as varchar(3)) c from a) aprime
where aprime.c='1a';
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT CAST(id AS VARCHAR(3)) + CAST(x AS VARCHAR(3)) AS 'output' FROM a) x
 WHERE x.output = '1a'
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Bill Karwin's answer, I'd consider a computed column to encapsulate the expression so it can be reused elsewhere

```
ALTER TABLE a ADD COLUMN c AS cast (id as varchar(3)) +cast (x as varchar(3))
```

Comment: Be careful with computed columns though. They are good for simple column-derived formulas like this. But I would not recommend them for more advanced calculations that you will wrap in functions, as referencing functions in computed columns will prevent you from modifying the function.

Comment: Personally, I'd live with this restriction, but perhaps one point of computed columns is to reduce the use of UDFs elsewhere. AKA transferring the calculation into the table definition from code, views etc

Comment: I think it would be better to add a view rather than to add a calculated column as eidylon says .

Comment: Not all brands of RDBMS support computed columns in the way you show.  You'd have to write a trigger in some cases.  Other RDBMS may allow you to use *expression indexes* so you don't need the extra column.

Comment: @Bill. OP said SQL Server though so may as well leverage that

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery as demonstrated by Bill Karwin. However: **Please** I urge you, **do not do this**. Please use the where clause you "don't want to use".

The following permits the query optimiser to determine an index to use and make the query run efficiently.

```
where id=1 and x ='a'
```

The following (and Bill's equivalent) *prevents* the query optimser from using indexes and will contribute to general performance problems on your server.

```
where cast (id as varchar(3))+cast (x as varchar(3))='1a'
```